# Can a minor live abroad without parental consent?

Tags: usa, mexico

I have two very abusive divorced parents. I am going to turn 17 and I am a citizen of the of the USA and Mexico. I have plans to move to Mexico City and I am not going to tell my parents, so basically I am running away. Is the US able to make me come back to the US? I am under the impression that they cannot because I am a Mexican Citizen and they cannot force me to leave my country.

Comment: Questions about migrating to an other country belong on Expatriates and I will move it there. But in general, you need parental permission of both parents and you need money which your parents should supply till you turn 18.

Comment: You may need to get a Mexican court to grant permission to you to live independently from your parents.  Mexican, because you will be in Mexico.  You may need a similar order from a US court, since that is where your parents are.  Look for "emancipation of a minor." There may be a charitable organization where you live that can give you more information, legal aid to put your case before the court, or other support.

Comment: Before applying to a Mexican court, the OP would need to get into Mexico. I believe for an under-18 who is a citizen of Mexico (including dual citizens), traveling without parents, that will require parental authorization. Look for legal aid in the US first.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the specific case of a minor who somehow manages to travel without parental consent, but in general treaties favor having custody issues decided by the courts in the jurisdiction where the minor normally lives, regardless of nationality.

In your situation there are probably already court orders in effect, related to your parents' divorce, about who has what types of custody and where you should live.

Whether moving to Mexico City is safe will depend on how well you know the city and what sort of support network you have there.

I suggest consulting a trusted adult, or your local child protective services. You may be able to get different living arrangements that will protect you from parental abuse without moving to Mexico.